# error: incompatible types in assignment of `int' to `int[2]'

Tags: c++

The following C++ code:

```
int iBlocks[9][2];
class System{
  void setBlocks(){
    int iUCtr = 0;
    int iUYCtr = 105;
    while(1){
      int iUXCtr = 180;
      while(1){
        iBlocks[iUCtr] = 0;          //error happens here.
        iBlocks[iUCtr][0] = iUXCtr;
        iBlocks[iUCtr][1] = iUYCtr;
        iUCtr += 1;
        iUXCtr += 120;
        if(iUXCtr>420) break; 
      }
      iUYCtr += 120;
      if(iUYCtr>345) break;
    }
  }
  public:
    System(){
      setBlocks();
      cout << "Block settings set..." << endl;   
    }
};
```

MinGW g++ produces this error:

```
incompatible types in assignment of `int' to `int[2]'
```

The problem is at `iBlocks[iUCtr] = 0;`.

When I changed iBlocks to a pointer, it worked.  Can someone explain to me what is going on under the hood?

Comment: That line is wrong.  What are you trying to do?  You may be able to just remove it.

Comment: Well... what is it that you were _trying_ to do? We can't tell from the code because, as you've discovered, the code _doesn't do that thing_. `iBlocks[iUCtr] = 0;` is wrong because `iBlocks[iUCtr]` is an array of `int`s and `0` is just one `int`, as the error said.

Comment: You can't access the array like that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The code is supposed to initialize the (e.g.) iBlocks[0] to 0; I'm trying to create a 2dimensional array where the first dimension will tell the program whether a value was set unto it (its default is 0) and the 2nd dimension will have the X and Y coordinates...

Comment: @JamesMichaelAdoremos: It makes no sense to "initialise an array to 0". An array is a collection of multiple objects. "0" is not multiple objects. Even if you had an array of size 1, it's an array. This is not optional; you can't just change it to be an `int` whenever you feel like it.

Comment: Oh, I just have realized what I have done... Tsk, _made a fool out of me..._ Haha... Thanks guys. :)

Comment: If you found it a solution, please write it as an answer; don't edit away the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `iBlocks[iUCtr] = 0;` is not required. Delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set a whole "row" of a matrix with the "0" value.  The compiler won't let you do that.

Perhaps you missed the second index, since iBlocks is a matrix, what you would need is something like this:

```
iBlocks[iUCtr][SecondIndex] = 0
```

If instead you are trying to initialize a whole matrix with Zeros, write a function to do that.

Comment: That would be pointless. He already fills both elements in the sub-array just afterwards. I suspect he is trying to "set a null pointer" because someone has been _lying_ to him and saying "arrays are just pointers"

Answer (score 2):

You try to assign the value 0 to an array of int[2].
I think you can just remove the complete line as the item is filled already in the following two lines of code.